# How to convert python datetime

Tags: python, python-datetime

I want to run a script with CET time schedule,
so, how to get python datetime.time for CET 14:55 ?

```
import datetime

utc = datetime.timezone.utc
ftime = datetime.time(hour=13, minute=55, tzinfo=utc)
stime = datetime.time(hour=14, minute=25, tzinfo=utc)
```